# Counting the duplicate and setting the record in calculated column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Student_Information`, with columns and data like:

```
ID StudentName FatherName NIC  No_of_Childrens Date_of_Birth Date_of_Admission 
1   Mark        John      85                      2010-04-01    2015-04-19  
2   Akbar       Aslam     89                      2009-05-01    2015-04-19
3   Percul      John      85                      2010-04-01    2015-04-19  
4   Ali         Aslam     89                      2009-05-01    2015-04-19
5   Diglor      John      85                      2010-04-01    2015-04-19  
6   Sabi        Aslam     89                      2009-05-01    2015-04-19
```

I want to count the `NIC` column for duplicates and give numbers to `no of childs` column. Like this:

```
ID StudentName FatherName NIC No_of_Childrens Date_of_Birth Date_of_Admission 
1   Mark        John    85        1              2010-04-01 2015-04-19  
2   Akbar       Aslam   89        1              2009-05-01 2015-04-19
3   Percul      John    85        2              2010-04-01 2015-04-19  
4   Ali         Aslam   89        2              2009-05-01 2015-04-19
5   Diglor      John    85        3              2010-04-01 2015-04-19  
6   Sabi        Aslam   89        3              2009-05-01 2015-04-19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below snippet -

```
SELECT ID, StudentName, FatherName, NIC,No_of_Childrens,Date_of_Birth, Date_of_Admission
FROM
(
SELECT ID, StudentName, FatherName, NIC,Date_of_Birth, Date_of_Admission,No_of_Childrens = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY NIC ORDER BY ID)
FROM Student_Information) A ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you its working like a charm. but i want to update the existing record. i want to insert the value of Number_of_Children to its column not just calculating

Comment: One way of doing that will be storing the data (retrieved from above query) into some temp table and then join the temp table with `Student_Information` based on `ID`.
Query - 
`SELECT ID, StudentName, FatherName, NIC,Date_of_Birth, Date_of_Admission,No_of_Childrens = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY NIC ORDER BY ID)
INTO #temp
FROM Student_Information ORDER BY ID;

UPDATE SI SET SI.No_of_Childrens = #temp.No_of_Childrens
FROM Student_Information SI INNER JOIN #temp ON SI.ID = #temp.ID`

Comment: Thank you very much. can i give numbers according to Date_of_Birth. I mean 1st check same NIC then Compare Date_of_Birth the earlier date_of_birth give no one the next to 2 and so on....

Comment: Yes. You can choose by which column you want to determine the duplicate and change the query accordingly. Just replace `NIC` with `Date_of_Birth` after the `PARTITION BY` or use like this `NIC,Date_of_Birth`